# How to get Index of an Entity in a Sentence in Spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to know if there is an elegant way to get the index of an Entity with respect to a Sentence. I know I can get the index of an Entity in a string using `ent.start_char` and `ent.end_char`, but that value is with respect to the entire string.

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u"Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion. Apple just launched a new Credit Card.")

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```

I want the Entity `Apple` in both the sentences to point to start and end indexes 0 and 5 respectively. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to subtract the sentence start position from the entity start positions:

```
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char-ent.sent.start_char, ent.end_char-ent.sent.start_char, ent.label_)
#                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Output:

```
Apple 0 5 ORG
U.K. 27 31 GPE
$1 billion 44 54 MONEY
Apple 0 5 ORG
Credit Card 26 37 ORG
```

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hi, Can you please explain the logic here?Why are we subtracting the sent_start position from both?

Comment: @ShrinidhiNarasimhan `ent.sent.start_char` is an offset of the sentence that must be subtracted from both start and end indices.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew! However doing so for the ent.end_char gives me the incorrect indices. It gives me indices which are -ve.   `entity_start=entity.start_char-entity.sent.start_char
                        entity_end=entity.end-entity.sent.start_char`

Comment: @ShrinidhiNarasimhan Then your scenario is different from the one in the OP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! Just rechecked. Seems I made a mistake in my code. Need to write is as entity.end_char instead of entity.end.